# Specific Disadvantages of PHP compared to Python via code examples?

Tags: php, python

There appears to be an overwhelming acceptance that php is a "poorly designed" language as compared to python.

As I have limited experience I am not able to fully understand this conceptually or practically...I'm still in the
"Php works fine so far" camp...but id like to be educated.

I am specifically interested in their use in web development
Can people give examples along with simple code to show why php can be problematic in important 
practical scenarios?

Relevant answers that are fundamentally not related to code are welcome as well...

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Overwhelming? This question smells of rankbait.

Comment: personal preference for what?...the idea is to try to understand what some people prefer and what others don't. Java is naturally suited to Object oriented programming...C isn't....if one "prefers" to work with object oriented programming one should probably use Java or C++....so things might not be as clear cut here..but the idea is to understand what one might even prefer...sorry if its been done before...but its certainly a valid question...

Answer (score 4):

The [PythonVsPhp](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonVsPhp) page on the PythonInfo Wiki has an excellent summary of the differences along with some heated retorts and counter-retorts.

Comment: This is written on a Python wiki...how objective is it?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder If it weren't a Wiki, I'd share your concern. But take a look at the debated items.  Supporters for both get a fair say.